# Amazon RDS suddenly not working and unable to connect

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm using an Amazon RDS with MySQL, and I connect to it via another EC2 machine. I correctly set the Security Groups; and it has been working good for two days.
Today, for a test I scaled the RDS istance from db.t1.micro to db.m1.small. And it worked. Then I re-scaled down to db.t1.micro and rebooted the machine.

Now, I'm unable to connect. I have changed nothing on the EC2 machine, the hostname for RDS is the same, and the RDS is running.
I also tried to reboot two more times the RDS, but nothing changed...

How come? It seems to be a problem in Amazon AWS...

Comment: Probably a better question to ask Amazon's tech support.

Comment: I tried again to connect, and now it seems working. I don't know why, but I got this problems with RDS twice, perhaps it needs a lot of time (several minutes) to reboot after scaling?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your RDS instance got hosed. Do you have any snapshots where you can create another one from ? I performed the same operations that you described and my database works fine.  You can also check the logs:

[image: RDS Logs]

Hope it helps.